# How to have several bootstrap buttons active at a time on one page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm having trouble showing more than one button active to the user when using the bootstrap button class. I have two rows of buttons - I want the user to be able to select one value from each of the rows, and I want both selected buttons to show as active so that user can easily see the choices they selected. Currently, if the user selects one button, it becomes highlighted, but once they select another button from another row, the second button is then highlighted, but the first button no longer displays as active to the user.

So I have:

```
<div class="btn-group text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="row 1 choice 1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="row 1 choice 2" />
              </div>
<div class="btn-group text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="row 2 choice 1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="row 2 choice 2" />
              </div>
```

The user is directed to select one option from the first and second row and I just want both buttons to show they are active (by being indicating the darker color) once they are selected, instead of just one being able to be active at a time.

Comment: add a screenshot or URL with your question

Comment: The behavior you want to implement can be achieved through toggle button. Please check this link http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to remove the class "active" from all the buttons and then add the "active" class to the pushed button:

```
<script>
    $(".btn-primary").click(function () {
        $(btn-primary").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Just had to add a period in front of the btn-primary listed for it tow work with your code!

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the `active` class on them when they are clicked like this:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" value="row 1 choice 1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="row 1 choice 2" />
              </div>
<div class="btn-group text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="row 2 choice 1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" value="row 2 choice 2" />
              </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to toggle an active class on your buttons. Also there are problem around using a button element becuase they have default behavior when clicking them which messes the styling up. I have changed them to anchor tags and it works perfectly.

```
<div class="btn-group text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-primary"  data-value="row 1 choice 1"></a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary"  data-value="row 1 choice 2"></a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-value="row 2 choice 1"></a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-value="row 2 choice 2"></a>
</div>

<script>
    $(".btn-primary").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active")
    });
</script>
```

If you need to retrieve values from your anchor tags with javascript you can use html 5 data attribute as I have done:

html:

```
<a id="btn4" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="row 2 choice 2"></a>
```

Js:

```
 $("#btn4").data("value")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. the only problem is I only want one button in each row to be active at a time. With this method, each button selected remains active

Comment: Okay i didnt understand your question. 
Do you want to be able to have only 1 selected in each group? Or can you have 2 selected in a group?

Comment: 1 selected in each group